# How to load rda/RData files in an environment using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

As the question ask how can I load rda/RData files with stock time series in an environment using quantmod

I am downloading AAPL time series data using this code

```
data <- getSymbols("AAPL",auto.assign=FALSE)
save(data,file="/home/user/folder/AAPL.rda")
rm(data)
```

I want to load **AAPL.rda** files in an environment using quantmod and I tried this

```
data<-new.env()
getSymbols("/home/user/folder/AAPL", src="rda", env=data, auto.assign=FALSE)
```

and it shows AAPL's time series in command line

```
2009-08-28    172.27    172.49   168.53     170.05   113425200      22.36121
2009-08-31    168.16    168.85   166.50     168.21    77834400      22.11925
2009-09-01    167.99    170.00   164.94     165.30   117257000      21.73660
2009-09-02    164.62    167.61   164.11     165.18    91062300      21.72082
```

but its not loading to the `data` enviroment

```
> ls(data)
character(0)
```

How to find solution for this?

Comment: If you want to load a file, just use... `load`. Try `load("/home/user/folder/AAPL.rda",envir=data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Library(financialInstriments) is what you want... the function getSymbols.FI() will do exaclty what you want...  setSymbolLookup() is another..   you keep .rda files in folders like this.... data1/data1.rda inside your working directory...